Why I am getting different KV cache?
I have taken Squad 2.0 dataset for inferencing Gemma 2B model.
When I provided model with 1st datapoint truncating till 36 tokens and same datapoint truncating till 80 tokens.
I am getting slightly different KV cache for first 36 tokens, why is that so?
Example:
Input 1 Token: [[     2, 235309,  19647, 235307]]
Input 2 Token: [[     2, 235309,  19647, 235307,   1261,    573,   2872]]
Above is just example not actual prompt. Input 2 is extension of input 1.
When giving input 1 and input 2 to model we will get KV cache. The KV cache of first 4 tokens should be same theoretically. But I am getting difference in both the KV cache only when Input 2 has more than 54 tokens in my case. Otherwise I am getting same KV cache.
Please help me figure out why this case is happening.
